# Closing a rendering report from ReportViewer sometimes hangs application

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I am having an issue when trying to close a report that is still rendering in the ReportViewer inside a VB.NET application. When I try to close the still rendering report (report with over 600 pages) it will SOMETIMES seemingly close the report but hang the entire application (inclusing the minimize/maximise functions) but still show it as "Running" in task manager.

I have implemented the `CancelRendering` Function but this seems to only help in situations where the report was going to close properly in the first place. I have tried all sorts of different values for the timeout including "-1" and "0" but nothing makes a difference. The only constant thing with this error is when the report hangs the application the `CancelRendering` returns "`False`".

Here is a snippet of the ReportBase class that is runnning the WinForms.ReportViewer:

```
Private Sub ReportBase_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    Dim parent As MainForm
    parent = Me.ParentForm ' Get the parent form of this child

    ' If there is only one child left and this child is closing then show the explorer bar
    If parent.MdiChildren.GetLength(0) = 1 Then
        parent.UltraExplorerBar1.Show()
        parent.HomeToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
        MainForm.Panel2.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ReportBase_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim millisecondsTimeout As Integer = 100 'waits for the report to cancel rendering
    Dim returnValue As Boolean
    returnValue = ReportViewer2.CancelRendering(millisecondsTimeout)
    MessageBox.Show(returnValue.ToString)
End Sub


Private Sub ReportBase_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    With ReportViewer2
        'Get reports from remote server

        .ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote
        .ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New System.Uri(ReportServer)

    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT 1:** 
Something I forgot to mention. I checked my threads and the "Rendering" thread remaind open when the report hangs my application.

Also when CancelRendering is set to "-1" the report never closes. The application just hangs with the report still open.

**EDIT 2:**
This is only happening when I open the report in "`Printlayout`" aka `ReportViewer.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)`. When the report is opened normally it loads all 413 pages in an instant. When loaded in "`PrintLayout`" the report loads each page (over 600 in this mode) one by one very slowly. I think it has something to do with exiting the thread that is loading each of these pages.

I could not get the error when loading into the regular mode.

I would run a profiler session on the report server but unfortunatly I do not have access at this time. If I do gain access I will update with the results.

**EDIT 3:**
When the report closes correctly (and the CancelRendering works properly) I get "Report processing was cancelled" and `CancelRendering` returns true

[image: works]

When the report does not stop rendering before closing, it keeps rendering after the `CancelRendering` fires and returns a False.

[image: does not work]

Another thing I discovered is that if I close the entire application instead of just the report, The application will close but stay open only as a process in Task Manager. this makes me think it really is a issue closing the Render thread. The threads also do not have locations when the application is hanging.

[image: threads]

Answer (score 0):

This is the makeshift way I am getting around this problem. Even though this is keeping my application from hanging, I would love to know the ACTUAL solution to this issue.

```
Private Sub ReportBase_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim millisecondsTimeout As Integer = 0 'waits for the report to cancel rendering
    Dim returnValue As Boolean = False
    While Not returnValue
        returnValue = ReportViewer2.CancelRendering(millisecondsTimeout)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(10)
    End While
End Sub
```

I figured if the issue is only sometimes arising I could keep trying to cancel the rendering of the report until it actually works. I guess this works because the `CancelRendering` function must have points where it can and cannot be stopped. When I saw the report kept rendering even after a failed attempt to sto it i figured why not just loop the `CancelRendering` until it works.